# Multiply plant from motherplant

Tags: houseplants, growth, propagation

I‘ve multiplied a lot of Monstera plants in the past and know, that when you cut of a stem, put it in water, the roots will start to grow and you can pot them.

Now I have a big Monstera Plant which grows vertical with no "branches“.

The plant is called: Strelitzia nicolai

Does anyone know how to multiplay this plant, without the risk of the motherplant diying?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Ahh..it's easy!!
Just divide the rhizomes (the part below soil) and repot them and you are done!

[Wiki-how](https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-a-Bird-of-Paradise-Plant) shows:
[image]

Let your plant grow a bit and let it produce pups. Also you can do it before it producing pups, you just need healthy, mature rhizome. When you think your plant is matured enough, pull it out from soil, clean it and break the rhizomes(roughly about 2-3 cm in length). Each rhizome will produce a plant.

Oh, another thing.. Strelitzia nicolai is not a Monstera!!